# How does Google News Robot works?

Tags: php, symfony, google-news

I'm building a new project with Symfony2 where I need to pull some articles from several websites over the web to my website. I know I have to be careful about how to display those information but that's not the point.

My question is, how could I build a robot that pick up those articles ? Then, I guess, I'll have to review it into my code and filter those articles with tags, titles or key words.

Which technology should I use ? can I do that with php ? What do I need ? Which knowledge ? Should I use RSS ?
The more precise the answer is (with references if you have some) the better !

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is essentially the same as a search engine, with some tweaks for news sites. [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs101/CourseRev/feb2012) offers a course in the basics of a search engine, so you could start there.